# How to store my gnome terminal color palette

Tags: gnome-terminal, vim

I use terminal and vim extensively, while writing code. I have created a color palette which is based on readability and easy-use with an autocomplete plugin(obtain plugins from [Pydiction : Tab-complete your Python code](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=850), [Auto Pairs : Insert or delete brackets, parens, quotes in pair.](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3599) ).

I want to backup these settings so I can reuse them when I have problems with my current installation (12.04, by the way, I plan a clean Ubuntu 12.10 install in October). Are these settings are stored in a config file? Or if they are stored in gconf/dconf, how can I write a shell script to restore it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

gnome terminal color palette details are stored under directory `~/.gconf/apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/`

In Default directory you will be able to see a file named `%gconf.xml`. This file stores all palette related data. So you can backup all the files under directory `~/.gconf/apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/`

To view the configurations: Open **gconf-editor** using dash and navigate to apps->gnome-terminal->Profiles->Default

For vim configuration backup, just use `find` or `locate` command to find .vimrc file and backup it

Comment: Thanks! I've never known that gconf was filesystem based, I've thought that it was probably a database file somewhere.

Comment: You are welcome :). Yes you are right. GConf is a simple filesystem based database for storing application preference

Comment: Note that the gnome-terminal bits are obsolete now. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/967517/backup-gnome-terminal/967535 for updated instructions.