# how to color each new command in terminal?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

As I am running commands in the terminal, some times when the resulted log is larg, I get lost looking for the command line it self.

And some times when I need to distinguish between logs of the previous command and logs of the command after ..

So, what's the recommended way to solve this issue? I thought about colors, but, I have no idea what to do or how to configure the terminal?

Is there another terminal which support colors, bold, or may be italic .. ??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To color each new command in terminal, you've to edit ~/.bashrc file.
To do this,

```
gedit ~/.bashrc
```

Uncomment the line

```
# force_color_prompt=yes
```

to

```
force_color_prompt=yes
```

Then, You can restart the terminal or do

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: so, do I have put the path for .bashrc? or ~ will find it? can you please explain what is the ~ ?

Comment: ~ stands for **home** folder like / stands for **root** folder.

Comment: can I change the default color for background and text?

Comment: I've not tried that yet as I'm happy with the default. But you can try http://askubuntu.com/questions/218930/how-can-i-create-a-built-in-color-scheme-for-gnome-terminal/236229#236229