# Gnome-Terminal profile configuration file

Tags: command-line, configuration

i have worked very hard on customizing my terminal's profile colors. and i really i want to use the same setting for future Ubuntu releases.
is there a way i can have a versatile mean for saving these terminal profile setting. just like in eclipse we can save theme setting into a file that we can plug into any eclipse release.
are terminal profile settings saved to some configuration file that can be kept aside to be plugged into any future releases of the terminal ?

Comment: Here you can find answer to this question https://askubuntu.com/questions/967517/backup-gnome-terminal