# inconsolata font doesn't show up on terminal preferences

Tags: 16.04, fonts, i3-wm

I'm on 16.04 running the `i3` window manager.

I recently installed the inconsolata font using:

```
$ sudo apt-get install fonts-inconsolata
```

I updated the cache:

```
$ sudo fc-cache -fv
```

The font appears to be installed:

```
$ fc-list | grep -i inconsol
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/inconsolata/Inconsolata.otf: Inconsolata:style=Medium
```

Yet, when I try to use in my terminal (by trying to set the font from the terminal's menu options Edit and then "Profile Preferences", it is not listed among the available fonts.

I've also launched the Unity tweak tool using:

```
$ unity-tweak-tool
```

… and I was able to set "inconsolata medium" as the "monospace font" but nothing changed. It's not really clear to me how the monospace font configured in the Unity tweak tool relates to the font used in the terminal, but like I said, nothing changed.

Finally, as another data point, here's what I see under `/usr/share/fonts`:

```
$ find /usr/share/fonts | grep -i  incons
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/inconsolata
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/inconsolata/Inconsolata.otf
```

## update

Based on a suggestion, I got the `.ttf` version from Google fonts and installed it in my system (and updated the fonts cache too). So now I see:

```
$ find /usr/share/fonts | grep -i incons
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/inconsolata
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/inconsolata/Inconsolata.otf
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/inconsolata/Inconsolata-Regular.ttf
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/inconsolata/Inconsolata-Bold.ttf
```

… and:

```
$ fc-list | grep -i incons
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/inconsolata/Inconsolata-Bold.ttf: Inconsolata:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/inconsolata/Inconsolata-Regular.ttf: Inconsolata:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/inconsolata/Inconsolata.otf: Inconsolata:style=Medium
```

The situation remains the same: I can't select "inconsolata" in my terminal's profile preferences.

Comment: Did you close and restart the terminal window?

Comment: @chaskes yes I did.

Comment: Possibly you need to run `fc-cache` as yourself also, i.e. without `sudo`.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson tried that, no luck.

Comment: Remove all the otf versions and run `fc-cache` again

Comment: @Anwar did that. Then run `fc-cache -fv` (both with and without `sudo`), closed the terminal, and opened an new terminal. Same thing.

Comment: Which terminal it is? And do you have font-manager installed?

Comment: `echo $TERM` says: `xterm-256color`. The Inconsolata font shows up on the `font-manager` application, but not on `Edit->Profile Preferences` on the terminal menu.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I am having the same issue on fresh installs of Ubuntu 18 on multiple different machines...

Comment: @Bill No never solved it, gave up instead.

Comment: @MarcusJuniusBrutus I found a way to work around this by dumping the configs with `dconf`, editing manually and then loading them back in. See this Q/A which helped me: https://askubuntu.com/questions/967517/backup-gnome-terminal

Comment: @Bill I believe the issue is Inconsolata identifies as a "Decorative" font, instead of "Monospace". Editing with FontForge may correct the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Inconsolata identifies itself as a "Decorative" font, instead of "Monospace". I am opening an issue on GitHub. In the meantime, you can edit the files in FontForge. (Element | Font Info | OS/2 | PFM Family)

[image: FontForge settings for Inconsolata]