# Gnome-terminal profiles do not show up in gconf-editor in 16.04 LTS

Tags: command-line, unity, gnome, gnome-terminal, colors

I am trying to change my terminal colors to Zenburn. The normal way to do this is through `gconf-editor`. However, when I use `gconf-editor` I don't see any profiles for `gnome-terminal`! When I go into `gnome-terminal` and select preferences I can see two profiles (unnamed and zenburn, appropriately).

When I fire up the handy Zenburn script it also confirms there are no profiles found:

```
Please select a Gnome Terminal profile
expr: syntax error
You have selected:
  Profile: (gconf key)
```

I am using Unity on 16.04 LTS. Is there a setting I need to set to do this properly?

Comment: Newer `gnome-terminal` versions use `dconf`/`gsettings`. Use `dconf-editor`, or command line `dconf` (see e.g. https://askubuntu.com/questions/967517/backup-gnome-terminal for some idea).

Comment: thankfully ubuntu 18.04 choice of colors are much better than 16.04 ... now no need to work to install palette the UI color `tango` is close enough to monokai color scheme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there are no good resources online to do this so hopefully this helps. Everything changed in 16.04 LTS. As mentioned in the comments, `dconf-editor` needs to be installed.

Once installed, the profiles will be found under `org > gnome > terminal > legacy`.

In order to get the palette, background color, foreground color, and bold color to show up as keys you can simply fiddle with the color settings in the profile via the terminal profile preferences menu. Once that's done for Zenburn copy the color settings from [this gist](https://gist.github.com/planbnet/1422472). You will not be able to use the gist as-is. Instead, you will have to manually copy each color into the right spot. Maybe later on I'll write a script to do this automatically.