# export/import gnome-terminal profile settings

Tags: gnome-terminal, settings

I have a several systems running Ubuntu 16.04.  I use git to manage my . files so I can maintain the same settings across systems, but the gnome-terminal settings are not in these files and instead in gconf.  I'm now adding an Ubuntu 18.04 system and I'd like to export my settings from 16.04 and import them on my 18.04 system.

How can I accomplish this for gnome-terminal settings from 16.04 to 18.04?

Answer (score 12):

After I posted the above question, I found the answer in the suggested answers:

Earlier answer: [Backup GNOME-Terminal | Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/967517/backup-gnome-terminal)

synopsis:
Save settings:

```
dconf dump /org/gnome/terminal/ > gnome_terminal_settings_backup.txt
```

Load the saved settings:

```
dconf load /org/gnome/terminal/ < gnome_terminal_settings_backup.txt
```

Comment: This exports an empty file on Ubuntu 19.10

Comment: this will dump more settings: `dconf dump /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX/ > material-theme-profile.conf` also see `https://gist.github.com/reavon/0bbe99150810baa5623e5f601aa93afc`